# How to fetch the first matching item from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given an array: `[1, 2, 3, 5, 8. 13]`

I can select all items greater than 3:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8. 13].select { |num| num > 3 }
```

(I am aware of the shorthand `select(&:>)` syntax, that is not the point here)

I can now return the first, easily.

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8. 13].select { |num| num > 3 }.first
```

But when the actual comparison is getting heavy, this is not very efficient. I am trying to optimize a case where we have arrays of 300+ items, the select will return one of the first in nearly all cases (and the array is already sorted). Moreover, our code to do the comparison is quite heavy (needs a roundtrip to the db, for example).

Is there a ruby shorthand to fetch the first and then stop? Similar to:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8. 13].each do |num|
   return num if num > 3
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13].find { |num| num > 3 }
#=> 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I was digging through the API docs for Array, but never looked at Enumerable. Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

Use Binary Search, it will find the matching element in a `O(log n)`

Here is a break down :

Slowest:

```
  2.1.2 :011 > [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13].sort.bsearch { |num| num > 3 }
 => 5
```

Slow:

```
 2.1.2 :010 > [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13].find { |num| num > 3 }
 => 5
```

Fastest:

```
2.1.2 :012 > [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13].bsearch { |num| num > 3 }
 => 5 
2.1.2 :013 >
```

Here is small script I just wrote to compare all methods:

```
 $ cat ./benchmark_find_bsrch.rb
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark/ips'

DATA = Array(0..10)

def find
DATA.find { |num| num > 3 }
end

def sort_bsearch
[10,9,8,4,5,6,1,2,3,7].sort.bsearch { |num| num > 3 }
end

def bsearch
DATA.bsearch { |num| num > 3 }
end

def select 
DATA.select { |num| num > 3 }
end

def lazy_select
DATA.lazy.select { |num| num > 3 }.first
end

Benchmark.ips do |bm|
  bm.report('find'){ find }
  bm.report('sort_bsearch'){ sort_bsearch }
  bm.report('bsearch'){ bsearch }
  bm.report('select'){select }
  bm.report('lazy_select') {lazy_select}
  bm.compare!
end
```

Which outputs the following :

```
util-scripts$ ./benchmark_find_bsrch.rb 
Calculating -------------------------------------
                find    63.607k i/100ms
        sort_bsearch    52.039k i/100ms
             bsearch    95.260k i/100ms
              select    57.218k i/100ms
         lazy_select    11.850k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
                find      1.130M (± 5.0%) i/s -      5.661M
        sort_bsearch    809.723k (± 6.5%) i/s -      4.059M
             bsearch      2.099M (± 6.1%) i/s -     10.479M
              select    929.578k (± 2.6%) i/s -      4.692M
         lazy_select    140.782k (± 8.1%) i/s -    711.000k

Comparison:
             bsearch:  2098632.5 i/s
                find:  1129912.5 i/s - 1.86x slower
              select:   929578.3 i/s - 2.26x slower
        sort_bsearch:   809722.5 i/s - 2.59x slower
         lazy_select:   140782.2 i/s - 14.91x slower
```

I hope you find this useful :)

Comment: It's crazy to sort the the entire array to find the first element that is greater than `3`. Suppose the array were huge and the first `3` was near the beginning of the crazy? You don't need a benchmark to conclude that sorting is absurd. Egad! There's an upvote!

Comment: `.find` is `O(n)`, `.sort` is `O(n log(n))`. It seems strange that a solution that uses `sort` is faster that the one that uses `find` on a large enough `array`.

Comment: Thanks @ Cary Swoveland , @ Akavall for your input , I got this upside-down ... however,  bsearch is still the king of all  for the given scenario  above . Hence , the array is  sorted .

Comment: I tried your benchmark for `DATA = Array.new(1e6) { rand 1e6 }`. The results were `find` fastest, `bsearch`  2.20x slower, `lazy_select` 12.66x slower, `select`, 126779x slower, `sort_bsearch`, 330906x slower. This is pretty much what I expected. Note that I did not suggest that `lazy` should be used for this problem. My argument for `lazy` is that it may be desirable if you wanted to obtain more than one value that satisfies the condition in the block. I misunderstood `bsearch`, thinking it also sorted first. Note `sort_bsearch` needs to be fixed in the script (`DATA.sort_bsearch...`).

Comment: @Akavail, you can't draw conclusions from a benchmark that only considers an array containing 11 elements. All methods have setup times, which can swamp the total if the collection is small.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland  ..good  point about the use of lazy..also, agree in the case of non-sorted find is optimal..

Comment: I wasn't familiar with [Array#bsearch](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), so I read the doc. It requires the array to be searched to be already sorted, which makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Enumerator#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy):

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13].lazy.select { |num| num > 3 }.first
  #=> 5
```

For your problem, [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is clearly best, but suppose the collection were large and you wanted the first `n > 1` elements greater than `3`? Using `lazy`, you could write:

```
(0..100_000_000_000).lazy.select { |num| num > 3 }.first(2)
  # => [4, 5]
```

which executes in a blink of the eye.

Comment: This works fine when optimising is needed **because the set is large**. But my problem needs optimizing **because the comparison is hard**: more like `[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13].select { |num| bcrypt(num) == bcrypt(3) }.first` where lazy won't help that much.

Comment: As I said, use `find` for your problem, but `lazy` may be useful for variants.  As to whether `select` should be used with `lazy`, that mainly depends on the size of the array. `select` will perform the block calculation for every element in the array (before executing `first`), whereas `lazy.select` will perform the same calculation, but will stop after selecting the first element that satisfies the condition. I think you are arguing against the use of `select`, `lazy` or not. I would not disagree.